# how to traverse and compare object inside an array elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, functional-programming

given the following array structure:

```
[{ _id: '1234', characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '1234',characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4567', characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4567',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4987',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object]]}]
```

how can I compare one array element with the next, and merge the object with the same id?

the end result is something like

```
[ { _id: '1234', characteristics: [ [Object], [Object] ,[Object], [Object] ]},
 { _id: '4567',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object] , [Object], [Object]]},
 { _id: '4987', characteristics: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

basically the objects inside both of the object with id of 1234 are merged together under characteristics.

I been staring at this for the past 2 hours, anyone have any idea? I'd prefer a more functional approach.

**Edit**: Solution that I am using based on Nenad Vracar's solution.

```
function mergeDupKey(data) {
    var o = {}
    return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
        if (!o[e._id]) {
            o[e._id] = e;
            r.push(o[e._id]);
        } else {
            o[e._id].characteristics = o[e._id].characteristics.concat(e.characteristics);
    }
    return r;
}, [])
}

var g = mergeDupKey(data)`
```

Comment: Could you share what approaches you have tried already?

Comment: You need to **reduce** your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` with one helper object. You can also use `concat()` instead of `...` and `push()` [`like this`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1284/)

```js
var data = [{ _id: '1234', characteristics: [[1], [2]]},
{ _id: '1234',characteristics: [[3], [4]]},
{ _id: '4567', characteristics: [[5], [6]]},
{ _id: '4567',characteristics: [ [7], [8]]},
{ _id: '4987',characteristics: [ [9], [10]]}];

var o = {}
var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!o[e._id]) {
    o[e._id] = e;
    r.push(o[e._id]);
  } else {
    o[e._id].characteristics.push(...e.characteristics);
  }
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: this is awesome! its much simpler than the approaches I have come up with. although this is ES6 only right? due to the ... spread operator in there

Comment: Yes spread operator is ES6 but you can use `concat()` instead https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1284/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` and a hash table to group the properties - see demo below:

```js
var array=[{_id:'1234',characteristics:[[1],[2]]},{_id:'1234',characteristics:[[3],[4]]},{_id:'4567',characteristics:[[5],[6]]},{_id:'4567',characteristics:[[7],[8]]},{_id:'4987',characteristics:[[9],[10]]}];

var result = array.reduce(function(hash) {
  return function(prev,curr){
    if(hash[curr._id]) {
      curr.characteristics.forEach(function(e){
        hash[curr._id].push(e);
      });
    } else {
      hash[curr._id] = curr.characteristics;
      prev.push({_id: curr._id, characteristics:hash[curr._id]})
    }
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `.reduce()`. There is no need for a helper object.

```js
var data = [{ _id: '1234', characteristics: [[1], [2]]},
{ _id: '1234',characteristics: [[3], [4]]},
{ _id: '4567', characteristics: [[5], [6]]},
{ _id: '4567',characteristics: [ [7], [8]]},
{ _id: '4987',characteristics: [ [9], [10]]}];

var found = false;
var result = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  prev.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj._id == curr._id) {
      obj.characteristics = obj.characteristics.concat(curr.characteristics);
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found)
    prev.push(curr);
  found = false;
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES5 approach:

```
var lst = [{ _id: '1234', characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '1234',characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4567', characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4567',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4987',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object]]}];

var result = [];

var findById = function(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        if (item._id === id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    var newitem = { _id: id, characteristics: [] };
    result.push(newitem);
    return newitem;
}

lst.forEach(function(item) {
    var aux = findById(item._id);
    aux.characteristics.concat(item.characteristics);
});

console.log(result);
```

Using ES6:

```
var lst = [{ _id: '1234', characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '1234',characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4567', characteristics: [[Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4567',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object]]},
{ _id: '4987',characteristics: [ [Object], [Object]]}];

var result = [];

lst.forEach(item => {
    var aux = result.find(it => it._id === item._id);
    if (!aux) {
        aux = { _id: item._id, characteristics: [] };
        result.push(aux);
    }
    aux.characteristics.concat(item.characteristics);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var data = [{ _id: '1234', characteristics: [["whatever"], ["whatever"]]},
            { _id: '1234', characteristics: [["whatever"], ["whatever"]]},
            { _id: '4567', characteristics: [["whatever"], ["whatever"]]},
            { _id: '4567', characteristics: [["whatever"], ["whatever"]]},
            { _id: '4987', characteristics: [["whatever"], ["whatever"]]}],
     lut = data.reduce((p,c) => p[c._id] ? (p[c._id].characteristics.push(...c.characteristics),p)
                                         : (p[c._id] = c, p), {});
  result = Object.keys(lut)
                 .map(k => lut[k]);
console.log(result);
```